# Multi-dimensional arrays: Variable length row?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, variable-length-array

It is possible to do variable length columns such as:

```
private int k[][] = new int[3][];

for(int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
   k[i] = new int[i+1];
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do variable length rows, if you know the length of a column?:

```
private int k[][] = new int[][5];

for(int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
   // How would you do this?
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Arrays in Java are always of a fixed length. If you need something variable in size, use ArrayList. It can also be nested, if you really have to do that.

Comment: Compiler: Cannot specify an array dimension after an empty dimension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, basically. A "multi-dimensional" array is just an array of arrays. So you *have* to know the size of the "outer" array to start with, in order to create it.

So your options are:

- Use the array in an inverted way as `array[column][row]` instead of `array[row][column]`
- Use a list instead, so you can add new rows as you go:

  ```
  List<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
  for (SomeData data : someSource) {
      Object[] row = new Object[5];
      ...
      rows.add(row);
  }
  ```

  (Or even better, encapsulate your concept of a "row" in a separate class, so you have a `List<Row>`.)